# How to pass props to a component passed as props in React?

Tags: reactjs

I want to pass props to a component that is passed as props like this:

```
<Field
      name="persons"
      component={Persons} 
/>
```

I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
component={<Person prop={prop} />}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: how will you  use the passed component?

Comment: As a dialog/popup and I wanna pass the status of show/hide and the function to show and hide

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can pass the component type and props in two different properties

```
<Foo component={Bar} componentProps={...} />
```

then in `Foo` component, you do this

```
 render() {
    const Component = this.props.component;
    const props = this.props.componentProps;
    return <div> ... <Component {...props}/> ...</div>
 }
```

**or** you can pass a function that renders you component like this

```
<Foo component={() => <Bar props />}/>
```

then in `Foo` component, you do this

```
 render() {
    return <div> ... {this.props.component()} ...</div>
 }
```

**or** you can do as you suggested in the question like this

```
<Foo component={<Bar props/>}/>
```

then in `Foo` component, you do this

```
 render() {
    return <div> ... {this.props.component} ...</div>
 }
```

its all depend on how you will use the passed component in `Foo` component, or in your case the `Field` component

Comment: @DennisVash are you familiar with render props? https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

Comment: My mistake you right I though it has different behavior, just checked it

Answer (score 2):

a component is nothing more than a function that returns a react component. when you do `<Person prop={prop} />` you are actually invoking that function in jsx style.

Therefore, you need to wrap your `Person` component into another function that returns `Person` like:

```
// props here is in case <Field> pass some props to component
component={(props) => <Person {...props} prop={prop} />}
```